# mouse click function for linux

Tags: c, qt, opencv

I am trying to build a virtual mouse by detecting finger movements with opencv. The finger detection is done. But I am stuck in mouse click function. 
My work is similar to this :
[http://8a52labs.wordpress.com/tag/colored-finger-tracking](http://8a52labs.wordpress.com/tag/colored-finger-tracking/)

But he has done in Windows. I am working in linux. I just want a library which provides me functions for doing left click, right click, mouse movement etc.
I am working with Fedora 16 , opencv and QT.

P.S - I have already moved the mouse cursor in Qt by QCursor::setPos(mouseX,mouseY);
But there is no function to make left click and right click.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this system-wide, rather than just restricted to your Qt application, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319519/how-to-insert-synthetic-mouse-events-into-x11-input-queue).

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a `QMouseEvent` through `QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)`.