# How can I send keyboard presses/mouse clicks to other GUI application in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, keyboard, awtrobot

I'd want to send mouse clicks, keyboard presses to already opened 3rd party GUI application from my Ruby program.

How can I send mouse clicks, keyboard presses to Ubuntu?

Comment: That depends on the GUI toolkit used in the application.

Comment: @sawa: it absolutely doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert synthetic mouse events into X11 input queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319519/how-to-insert-synthetic-mouse-events-into-x11-input-queue)

Comment: @n.m. If you can specify the coordinates of the mouse pointer, then you might be able to do it along the answer in your link, but how would you know the positions of the icons on the application? In order to click the right widget, I think you need to access the application through its GUI toolkit.

Comment: @sawa: Not necessarily.

Comment: @sawa: the coordinates can be recorded once by a human clicking on these widgets, then played back many times. That's generally the way GUI programs are tested in the industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) autoit like app for Ubuntu.
It's command-line so you can call it from Ruby

Comment: I've implemented it using XDoTool. But [I encountered a problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979465/how-to-prohibit-user-to-change-os-window-focus-type-keys-for-several-seconds-on)