# How to prohibit user to change OS window focus/type keys for several seconds on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, focus, x11, xdotool

I write automated tests for a website. One of the tests needs to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and type some letters to save a webpage including CSS/JS. The test should require Firefox to have window focus for those several seconds to be able to type the filename and click "Save" (currently XDoTool is used for pressing keys and clicking the mouse).

Sometimes I run the tests on my computer. I don't want to occasionally type something or change the window focus while the page is being saved, so I want to prohibit changing focus for those several seconds when those mouse clicks/key presses are running.

It's not possible to do it at the Webdriver level (a tool that I use for controlling the browser), so I think I should do it at the OS level. Can I prohibit the user from changing window focus or typing anything for a period of time? It may look like:

```
prohibit user from typing keys/change window focus
save page
allow user to type/change window focus
```

Comment: This may be of interest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx - perhaps you can explain at a higher level what you are trying to accomplish with your script, in case there's a better way than stealing control from your users.

Comment: If you take away my control over which window has focus, I won't be using your application.

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't write application that is intended to be used by users. I write automated tests for a website. During testing I'd want to press Ctrl+S to save a webpage. It requires window focus to be put to Firefox for several seconds. I don't want to occasionally type something or change window focus

Comment: @KeithThompson I've tried to clarify question

Comment: @AndreyBotalov: Ok. Stealing focus like that while a user is trying to use the system would be rude, but it sounds like that doesn't apply in your case; nobody is going to be trying to get other stuff done while the tests are running. The question at John's link, "What if two programs did this?", may still be relevant. And I wonder if there's some way to direct keystrokes and mouse clicks to a specified window without that window having focus. (I have no idea whether there is or not; it's not my area of expertise.)

Comment: I've asked the U&L mods if they think this might get better answers on their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that another way to achieve the desired effect would be to run Firefox and your automated tests on a nested X server (xf86-video-nested/Xephyr/Xnest).

```
$ Xnest :1
$ export DISPLAY=:1.0
$ firefox http://something/to/test &
$ your-test-script
```

Since the nested X server has it's own idea of the focused window, moving the focus on your desktop shouldn't affect it.

(If you don't actually need to see the test progressing, you could use a dummy X server (xf86-video-dummy/Xvfb/Xfake) instead)

Comment: How can I type Ctrl+S and enter filename in Firefox opened on another X server. (Currently I run it as `Xnest :1`, `export DISPLAY=:1.0`, `rake features`). `rake features` runs on this new X server

Comment: You should be able to just click inside the Xnest window to move the focus to the firefox window inside it and type into it.  Your automated tests using xdotool should interact with the nested X server provided DISPLAY is set correctly